# Notification in Oreo working sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working with notification in Android app

The notification is working perfectly in any version under O.

In Oreo its working (Showing/Pushing) sometimes and sometimes not, When I close app completely its work and also if I locked the device... but not more than 5 minutes after closing.

I do every things I saw.. I put permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

and I work with `JobIntentService`

also I checked for SDK VERSION after build notification...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
```

also I set Notification Channel:

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
```

but every that is not changing any thing...

I don't know what should I do.
any help please, and Thanks.

### my code:

### NotificationEventReceiver.class

```js
package com.example.android.homepharmacy.broadcast_receivers;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.android.homepharmacy.notifications.NotificationIntentService;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * WakefulBroadcastReceiver used to receive intents fired from the AlarmManager for showing notifications
 * and from the notification itself if it is deleted.
 */
public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION = "ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION";


    public static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                getTriggerAt(new Date()),
                60000 ,
                alarmIntent);
    }


    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Intent serviceIntent = null;
                if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive from alarm, starting notification service");
                    serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
                } else if (ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive delete notification action, starting notification service to handle delete");
                    serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentDeleteNotification(context);
                }

                if (serviceIntent != null) {
                    NotificationIntentService.startService(context);
                }
    }
}
```

### NotificationIntentService Methods:

```js
private void processStartNotification() {
        // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            
            final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context , CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setContentTitle("Drug Reminder for: " + memName)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.drug_icon)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                    .setContentText("Now its time for " + memName +
                            " to get " + drugName)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
            mainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, courseId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    mainIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setDeleteIntent(NotificationEventReceiver.getDeleteIntent(this));


            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            /* Create or update. */
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            // mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());



        }
        else {
            final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setContentTitle("Drug Reminder for: " + memName)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.drug_icon)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                    .setContentText("Now its time for " + memName +
                            " to get " + drugName)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, CourseActivity.class);
            mainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, courseId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    mainIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setDeleteIntent(NotificationEventReceiver.getDeleteIntent(this));


            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

        }


    }
```

Comment: What mean `notification not work`? Not showing? Not opening proper Activity?

Comment: sorry for not clear, I meant Not showing at all @Boken